# Add/remove items from array that goes into combobox

Tags: visual-studio-2010

This is what needs to be done.

This project / assigenment will maintain a list of movie titles in an array. The user can add and remove movie titles from the list, clear and print the list.

The form will contain a combo box initialized with the following entries: A Dependent's Pay, An American Resident, Dancing With Fools, Home By Yourself, and Ghost Man.

There will be six buttons on the form. An add button that will add an entry to the list using an input box. The user may not add a duplicate title to the list. A remove button that will remove the selected item off the list. An error is displayed if the user tries to add a blank title or remove a title without first selecting one. A clear all button will remove all the entries from the list. A count button will display in a message box the number of movie titles can be displayed. The print button will display the ‘Movie List’ report in a print preview window. Include your name on the report. And finally, an exit button.

This is what I have so far:

```
Public Class frmlist

  Dim movielist(100) As String

  Private Sub ExitToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ExitToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Me.Close()
  End Sub

  Private Sub frmlist_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    movielist(0) = "A Dependent's Pay"
    movielist(1) = "An American Resident"
    movielist(2) = "Dancing With Fools"
    movielist(3) = "Home By Yourself"
    movielist(4) = "Ghost Man"

    cboxlist.Items.AddRange(movielist)
  End Sub

  Private Sub AddToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles AddToolStripMenuItem.Click
    movielist(5) = InputBox("Enter a movie title: ", "Movies")
    cboxlist.Items.AddRange(movielist)
  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to add an additional item to the list that is already made and then display the new list in the combo box. The add menu click doesn't work, I get "value cannot be null." I'm not sure if I should be going about adding the right way.

Comment: Why you are using the html tag? o.O

Comment: o crap, my mistake lol, its visual basic 2010, im also working with some html stuff